# Match text from div then add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This divs are dynamically added

```
<div id="thumb"></div><div id="mssg"></div>
```

I want to add class to #thumb if the #mssg div contains specific texts, using jquery or javascript.

I tried this but not working. thanks for ur help.

```
var itemCode = ["haha", "hihi", "hehe"];
var regExpPattern = itemCode.join('|');
if($("#mssg").text().match(new RegExp(regExpPattern, 'i'))) {
 $("#thumb").addClass("wow");
}
```

This is my function how im adding the divs

```
function addChat(input, outcome) {
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("box");

let bot = document.createElement("div");
bot.id = "bot-wrap";
bot.innerHTML = `<div id="thumb"></div><div id="mssg">${outcome}</div>`;
mainDiv.appendChild(botDiv);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var text = $('#mssg').text();

if (text.indexOf('haha') >= 0 ||text.indexOf('hihi') >= 0 || text.indexOf('hehe') >= 0) {
$('#thumb').addClass("red");
};
```

```css
.red {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumb">Test</div>
<div id="mssg"> haha hihi hehe blablabla</div>
```

**And here is example how to use it on DOM change.**

```js
$("#mssg").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
var text = $('#mssg').text();
if (text.indexOf('haha') >= 0 ||text.indexOf('hihi') >= 0 || text.indexOf('hehe') >= 0) {
$('#thumb').addClass("red");
};
});


$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#mssg").append("<span>haha</span>");
});
```

```css
.red {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumb">Test</div>
<div id="mssg"></div>


<button id="add">Add to Div</button>
```

Comment: hi sir, ur sample is working if I add the divs right into the container, but not when divs are inserted dynamically. I updated my question. thanks

Comment: @88willr Try to add this code into your add div function. I can not replicate adding divs.

Comment: @88willr I added code for DOM change, see 2ed example. But it should work by just adding first solution at end of your add div function.

Comment: @88willr And if none of this work, bind DOMSubtreeModified from my 2ed example to element you are inserting all this divs that is already in DOM from start.